# how to make a friendly url in php with .htaccess file using php

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I have a problem in sending variables through URL by using **.htaccess** file.

I have two pages `projects.php` and `project-view.php` when I send variable from

`projects.php` to `project-view.php` it corrupted.

my `projects.php`

```
URL:G-Zip/Projects
```

project-view.php

```
URL:G-Zip/project-view.php?id=11042
```

I want URL to be like this **project-view/11042**.

**htaccess file:**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^projectview/([0-9]+)/?$ /view_project.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

what can u do in php code backend

Answer (score 0):

What you mean with `corrupted`?

I think that your problem is with the `.htaccess` file rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^projectview/([0-9]+)/?$ /view_project.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

I think that you have a error in the regular expression and according to your text, you don't have any `view_project.php` file, you have to change to: `project-view.php`.

> I want URL to be like this project-view/11042.

Try with backup your file and change the following line:

`RewriteRule ^project-view/(\d+)*$ ./project-view.php?id=$1`

This should treat `www.url.com/project-view/11` as `www.url.com/project-view.php?id=11`

Then in the `project-view.php` you will receive a `$_GET['id']` and you can work with it.

Hope it helps!